# Enabling Erdas ECW files in gdal

Tags: gdal, erdas-imagine, ecw

I want to enable read support from Erdas ECW files in gdal on windows.

I have GDAL binaries from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) and I also have a self compiled version.

When compiling myself I have found the options in nmake.opt and could add support myself, but if its possible I would rather add it to the precombiled distribution from gisinternals.  Is this possible? Or will I need to compile it my self?

Comment: If you use binaries from gisintenals, have you noticed the msi installer for ECW plugin http://gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1500-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip?

Comment: i had not. Will take a look

Comment: It worked, all the *.exe apps works, but the python scripts wont use the plugin. Is there python bindings from gisinternals also that can be added to python. (maybe the one i got from pip install is bad)

Comment: actually my python bindings came from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal since i could got get pip install to work.

Comment: On the same directory page I see "Installer for the GDAL python bindings (requires to install the GDAL core)"

Answer (score 1):

For read access the easiest way to get ECW support is through the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer.  Do an Advanced install, and in the libs section enable the gdal-ecw library.